# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect with ANT build

Tags: ant, xmltask

We are facing java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect while doing ANT build and this is happening in all java developer machine using ANT.
We tried to block below tag in web.xml as java.sun.com is cause of issue.

but still this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
Please help us to resolve this issue.

Below is stacktrace,

```
[xmltask] java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
  [xmltask]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.documentFromStream(XmlTask.java:354)
  [xmltask]     at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.documentFromFile(XmlTask.java:371)
  [xmltask]     at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.access$000(XmlTask.java:27)
  [xmltask]     at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask$InputFile.getDocument(XmlTask.java:215)
  [xmltask]     at com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask.execute(XmlTask.java:620)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
  [xmltask]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
  [xmltask]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
  [xmltask]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
  [xmltask]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
  [xmltask]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)

BUILD FAILED
C:\SIGMA\SIGMA_6.0\javasource_6.0\build\build_ecams_ehr.xml:2037: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: can you include your input xml file to the question

Answer (score 2):

Are you working behind a corporate proxy? This would block connections to the internet. You can configure your ANT script to work with proxies:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html

I have never used **xmltask** but I speculate it might be failing to resolve namespaces in your XML document.

```
<root xmlns:e="http://my.domain.com/exampleschema">

  <e:customer>
    <e:name>Joe Bloggs</e:name>
    <e:age>80</e:age>
  </e:table>

</root>
```

---

**xmltask** is not a standard ANT task, it is a 3rd party extension:

http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/

Comment: Thanks it is working now. Tue this is coz of network

Comment: I'd be intrigued to know which version of you're using. I patched later versions of it to specifically highlight proxy issues since the above was such a source of support issues for me (as the author)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a company network , case scenario is that your local network DEV/(WhatEver its named) environment connection is experiencing network connectivity issues.  Part of the build process is attempting to make an active connection to dynamically download a build ant-file and failing.

If proxy is configured to work with ant(check env ), check to see its properly configured otherwise
manually edit the proxy settings for ANT and it should built properly.  Click: 
   https://ant.apache.org/manual/proxy.html

This should work.